# how to remotely edit aws files using some kind of ide

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am using an ec2 instance and using `vi` to edit the bash file, python file. It is sometimes very inconvenient. What's the best way for me to use IDE to modify those file?  (where i could scroll and comment/uncomment easier) Thanks!

Comment: I imagine you're connected over SSH? What's your host operating system?

Comment: Vscode has an extension for remotely editing files.

Comment: While you could use a remote UI to do this I would strongly recommend you find another way.  Work on your code locally with your IDE, check it into a source code repository, and have a way to pull and build it on your EC2.  Yes, this is a bit more difficult but you will be much further ahead when someday your EC2 crashes or you have to have your code on multiple EC2's.

Comment: You could also install an X server + some desktop environment such as KDE or GNOME. Then you could install any IDE on the EC2 instance. To run it, you'd have to use SSH X11Forwarding...

Comment: https://github.com/libfuse/sshfs